# Issue indexing array

Tags: php

I'm having issue accessing the 4h level of embedded arrays. Lines 233 through 244 work as expected , but 245 and 246 give the following error.

Error

[07-Nov-2022 15:15:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in C:\Users\JAMESB\Documents\scripts\BC\orders\BC_orders.php on line 245

> [07-Nov-2022 15:15:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\Users\JAMESB\Documents\scripts\BC\orders\BC_orders.php on line 245 [07-Nov-2022 15:15:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in
> C:\Users\JAMESB\Documents\scripts\BC\orders\BC_orders.php on line 246 [07-Nov-2022 15:15:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\Users\JAMESB\Documents\scripts\BC\orders\BC_orders.php on line 246

Code:

```
233             $order['billing_address']['first_name'],
234             $order['billing_address']['last_name'],
235             $order['billing_address']['company'],
236             $order['billing_address']['street_1'],
237             $order['billing_address']['street_2'],
238             $order['billing_address']['city'],
239             $order['billing_address']['state'],
240             $order['billing_address']['zip'],
241             $order['billing_address']['country'],
242             $order['billing_address']['country_iso2'],
243             $order['billing_address']['phone'],
244             $order['billing_address']['email'],
245             $order['billing_address']['form_fields'][0]['value'],
246             $order['billing_address']['form_fields'][1]['value'],
```

Data Snippet

> ```
> 'billing_address' =>
> array (
>   'first_name' => 'thing',
>   'last_name' => 'ie',
>   'company' => '',
>   'street_1' => '2548 Vulcan St, Harvey, LA 70058',
>   'street_2' => '',
>   'city' => 'harvey',
>   'state' => 'Louisiana',
>   'zip' => '70058',
>   'country' => 'United States',
>   'country_iso2' => 'US',
>   'phone' => '9939933399',
>   'email' => 'stuff@stuff.net',
>   'form_fields' =>
>   array (
>     0 =>
>     array (
>       'name' => 'How did you hear about us?',
>       'value' => '',
>     ),
>     1 =>
>     array (
>       'name' => 'Are your sales tax exempt? ',
>       'value' => 'No',
>     ),
> ```

Apologies and thanks in advance

JimB

Comment: It sounds like `$order['billing_address']['form_fields']` is `null` in at least one case where you try to access it (although not in the specific example you've given). You'd have to look at the data in more detail to find out where/why.

Comment: ...or ColdFusion, for that matter? [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @ADysonIt shouldn't be but I could do an isempty check on form_fields and slap a NULL in the $order item corresponding to it.

Comment: Yes you could certainly do that as a precaution. But if it should't ever be null then you need to check for issues in the source data.

Comment: I was about sure I wasn't addressing it correctly some how, but couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my discussion in the comments with @ADyson and after further research, I discovered there were records entered before the "custom" form_fields were added causing a "required" branch of the data to not exist. A simple ternary assignment fixed the issue:

```
 $How_did_you_hear_about_us = (isset($order['billing_address']['form_fields'][0]['value'])) ? $order['billing_address']['form_fields'][0]['value'] : "";
$Are_your_sales_tax_exempt = (isset($order['billing_address']['form_fields'][1]['value'])) ? $order['billing_address']['form_fields'][0]['value'] : "";
```

Sometimes I need to talk things through and I'm the only real coder here. I really appreciate the support here! Thank you, thank you, thank you!